# Extract value from column with pandas lib (data frame)

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

original data frame:

| Date | Detail |
| --- | --- |
| 31/03/22 | I watch Netflix at home with my family 4 hours |
| 01/04/22 | I walk to the market for 3km and I spent 11.54 dollar |
| 02/04/22 | my dog bite me, I go to hospital, spend 29.99 dollar |
| 03/04/22 | I bought a game on steam 7 games spen 19.23 dollar |

result data frame:

| Date | Detail | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31/03/22 | I watch Netflix at home with my family 4 hours | 0 |
| 01/04/22 | I walk to the market for 3km and I spent 11.54 dollar | 11.54 |
| 02/04/22 | my dog bite me, I go to hospital, spend 29.99 dollar | 29.99 |
| 03/04/22 | I bought a game on steam 7 games spen 19.23 dollar | 19.23 |

Describe my question:

- If **Detail** Column does not contain specific string which is begin with sp.. and end with dollar
  then value in **Cost col** equal zero.
- If **Detail** Column does contain specific string which is begin with sp.. and end with dollar,
  then value in **Cost col** equal **value in the middle** of specific string which is begin with sp..
  and end with dollar.

I try to use regex but it's got first int that contain in the col like

| 01/04/22   | I walk to the market for 3km and I spent 11.54 dollar|  3    |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a regex pattern of a form such as:

```py
df['Cost'] = df['Detail'].str.extract(r'sp\D*([\d\.]*)\D*dollar')
```

This will look for the literal string `sp` and then any non-digit characters after it. The capture group (denoted by the `()`) looks for any digits or period characters, representing the dollar amount. This is what is returned to the `Cost` column. The final part of the pattern allows any number of non-digit characters after the dollar amount, followed by the literal string `dollar`.

The `pd.NA` for rows which don't have a cost can then be replaced with `0`:

```py
df['Cost'] = df['Cost'].replace({pd.NA: 0})
```

If you want to make any enhancements I used this site to test the regex: https://regexr.com/6ir6o